# improving query or logic in a oracle stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, relational-database, plsqldeveloper

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
CUSTOMER
CIF   SUMOFALLACCOUNTBALACE
A1    6000
A2    2000
A3    7000

ACCOUNT
ACCOUNTNUMBER  ACCOUNTBALANCE
B1             1000   
B2             2000
B3             3000
B4             4000
B5             5000

RELATION
CIF  ACCOUNTNUMBER
A1   B1
A1   B5
A2   B2
A3   B3
A3   B4
```

I need to update `SUMOFALLACCOUNTBALACE` in `CUSTOMER` table of all the available `ACCOUNTNUMBER`s  of respective `CIF`s using `RELATION` table.

The sample query I built for 1 by 1 `CIF` is :-

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET SUMOFALLACCOUNTBALACE =
  (SELECT SUM(ACCOUNTBALANCE)
   FROM ACCOUNT
   WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER IN
     (SELECT ACCOUNTNUMBER
      FROM RELATION
      WHERE CIF IN 
        (SELECT CIF
         FROM CUSTOMER
         WHERE CIF = 'A1')))
WHERE CIF = 'A1'
```

which is giving me right results but it is taking time when large data, also I need to pass `CIF` 1 by 1 in oracle procedure using loop.

Can anybody please suggest a better way to do this?

Thanks in Advance,
Gopal Arora

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a single statement which updates all `SUMOFACCOUNTBALANCE`s in one go:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER C
SET SUMOFALLACCOUNTBALACE =
  (SELECT SUM(A.ACCOUNTBALANCE)
   FROM RELATION R
        INNER JOIN ACCOUNT A
          ON (A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = R.ACCOUNTNUMBER)
   WHERE R.CIF = C.CIF)
```

However, in general, you should not store the results of computations due to the danger of the computation result not being kept up to date when the elements forming that computation are changed. It would be better if you did not have a `CUSTOMER.SUMOFALLACCOUNTBALACE` column and instead you calculated it from the base data when required. In this way you can be assured that its value is correct at all times.

```
SELECT C.CIF
      ,SUM(A.ACCOUNTBALANCE) SUMOFALLACCOUNTBALACE
FROM CUSTOMER C
     LEFT OUTER JOIN RELATION R
       ON (R.CIF = C.CIF)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT A
       ON (A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = R.ACCOUNTNUMBER)
```